# Window title bar and unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-10, titlebar

How do I change the color of the title bar for Windows 10 build? The screenshot in the attachment is an example. Also, how can we programmatically maximise the window? Screen.SetResolution only changes screen size. It doesn't maximise the window.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JgD7.png)

Comment: For screen maximization could you be meaning fullscreen? Screen.fullScreen = true;

Comment: No, by maximise I mean the same thing as what happens when you click on the maximise button on the title bar.

Comment: This looks like more UWP style window

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code from the Unity Forum:

```
 //Import the following.
 [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowText")]
 public static extern bool SetWindowText(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.String lpString);
 [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
 public static extern System.IntPtr FindWindow(System.String className, System.String windowName); //Get the window handle.
 windowPtr = FindWindow(null, "Old Window Title"); //Set the title text using the window handle.
 SetWindowText(windowPtr, "New Window Title - Yayyy");
```

[Link to Unity Forum](https://answers.unity.com/questions/148723/how-can-i-change-the-title-of-the-standalone-playe.html)

Comment: This is not really what the question was about!